# TestNG: @BeforeGroups gets called for every group entry even though I am running one group of tests

Tags: java, testng

I see a problem in my testNG tests, the test is as follows.

```
public class testNG {

    @BeforeGroups(groups = {"smoketests", "functionaltests"})
    public void before() {
        System.out.println("Before Groups");
    }

    @Test(groups = {"smoketests", "functionaltests"})
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }

    @AfterGroups(groups = {"smoketests", "functionaltests"})
    public void after() {
        System.out.println("After Groups");
    }
```

}

When I run the tests from testNG command line by

java -cp :libs/* org.testng.TestNG -testjar libs/testNGLib.jar -groups smoketests

(Assume that the test jar is in some libs folder)

The output I get is as follows

```
Before Groups
Before Groups
Test
After Groups
```

I am not sure why the BeforeGroups is called twice even though I am only interested in running the test that's part of the smoketests group.

The problem doesn't happen if I only have smoketests group in the @Test directive, but I still don't understand the issue with @BeforeGroups with multiple groups in place.

Comment: Which version do you use? Could you try the latest (6.9.12)?

Comment: I am using 6.8, let me try with the latest version you suggested,

Comment: I am still getting the same error with the latest version (the one I have is 6.9.10), which is not too old.

Comment: Ok, I reported the issue: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1108 Any help to fix it is welcome.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into the test NG code base.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the same issue while running the test suite.

```
<suite name="Test Suite">
    <test name="GroupTest">
          <groups>
              <run>
                <include name="sanity"/>
              </run>
          </groups>
          <classes>
              <class name="SampleTest"/>
          </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Below is the test class:

```
public class SampleTest {

    @BeforeGroups(groups = {"sanity","regression"})
    void beforeGroup(){
        System.out.println("Before Group");
    }

    @AfterGroups(groups = {"sanity","regression"})
    void afterGroups(){
        System.out.println("After Groups");
    }

    @Test(groups = {"sanity"})
    void m1(){
        System.out.println("m1");
    }

    @Test(groups = {"sanity","regression"})
    void m3(){
        System.out.println("m3");
    }
    @Test(groups = {"sanity"})
    void m4(){
        System.out.println("m4");
    }
    @Test(groups = {"regression"})
    void m5(){
        System.out.println("m5");
    }
    @Test
    void m6(){
        System.out.println(Sample.class.getName());
    }
}
```

So when I am runnting the testng.xml, getting the following result:

```
Before Group
m1
Before Group
m3
After Groups
m4
After Groups
```

The following is the result after changing the group name to regression.

```
Before Group
m3
After Groups
m5
After Groups
```

@BefroreGroups and @Aftergroups get executed for both the group entries. Using TestNG 6.11 version.

Answer (score 0):

Try use

`@BeforeSuite(alwaysRun = true)` instead of `@BeforeGroups(groups = {"smoketests", "functionaltests"})`

`@AfterSuite(alwaysRun = true)` instead of `@AfterGroups(groups = {"smoketests", "functionaltests"})`